# Use decorator to create engine in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have several DB instances on my MySQL server and I want to create a small library to work with them. All DBs have the same structure - same tables with the same columns. I use SQLAlchemy to work with this DBs, but I can't use one engine to establish connection to several DBs at the same time. So, let's take an example:

```sh
+----------+
| Database |
+----------+
| DB1      |
| DB2      |
| DB3      |
| DB4      |
+----------+
```

All of them have structure:

```sh
+----------------+
| Tables_in_DB_N |
+----------------+
| table_1        |
| table_2        |
| table_3        |
+----------------+
```

So, I have come with an idea to use a decorator to create engine and `Session` class:

```py
Session = None
def decor(func, user=USERNAME, passw=PASSWORD, host=HOSTNAME, port=POST, db=DB):
    def real_decor(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{passw}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(user=user, passw=passw, host=host, port=port, db=db))
            global Session
            Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return real_decor
```

and function using this decorator example:

```py
@decor(db='DB1')
def get_db1_table1_values():
    session = Session()
    values = session.query(Table1).all()
    session.close()
    return values
```

This solution works. I don't really like hack with `global Session`... So, are there any other ways to do this feature?

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting problem, without knowing more about the lifecycle of your application it's hard to find a solution that will fit your usecase but here's an attempt:

```
def another_decor(user=USERNAME, passw=PASSWORD, host=HOSTNAME, port=PORT, db=DB):
    def real_decor(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{passw}@{host}:{port}/{db}'.format(user=user, passw=passw, host=host, port=port, db=db))
            session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            return func(session, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return real_decor
```

With this decorator it injects the session directly into the calling function, and avoids the use of the `global` keyword. Doing this requires the database accessing functions to be defined like this:

```
@another_decor(db='three')
def get_three_table1_values(session):
    session = session()
    query = session.query(Table1).all()
    session.close()
    return query
```

Decorating every database accessing function with it's own `Engine` and `Session`, depending on how SQLAlchemy manages its database connections, could easily exhaust your connections to the database.

MySQL typically runs in memory and based on [SQLAlchemys documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html) I think it will pool connections. So this usage may be okay.

Comment: The engine holds the pool. An application should usually have only 1 engine per database.